# To what degree does this Haskell code satisfy this specification?

Tags: haskell, recursion, specifications

**Listing 1** is a Haskell class signature and instance from a [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225122360_An_Image-Schematic_Account_of_Spatial_Categories).
The `isIn person house` function is supposed to return true if a person is in a given house or a given room.

**Listing 1**

```
class CONTAINMENT container for where
 isIn :: for -> container -> Bool


instance CONTAINMENT House Person where
 isIn person house =
         (container person = house) || isIn (container person) house
```

There are errors in the definition of `isIn person house`, which I wish to ignore for this post.

Instead I wish to consider **Listing 1** together with the **Textual Description** below  (from the [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225122360_An_Image-Schematic_Account_of_Spatial_Categories)) as a **Specification** (i.e. a reasonable representation of the specifiers intention).

**Textual Description**

> The axiom for isIn uses variables for individuals of type Person
>   (person) and House (house) and states that the person is in the house
>   if the house contains her or, recursively, if the house contains a
>   container (e.g., a room) containing her. To state this, I use a
>   representation of state as a labeled field container, here assumed to
>   be defined for person types.

From the **Specification** it seems that:

- A person may be in a room.
- A room may be in a house.
- A person may be directly in a house, without any room information.
- A person may be in a room that is in a house and thus may be deemed to be in the house.
- To be useful, the room needs information about the house containing it.
- The person contains information about their location. Can a person be both in a room and in the house containing the room? In other words do we have an inclusive or exclusive or in `isIn`?
- From the real world domain: every room must be in a house, it is impossible to be in a room that is not in a house.

  **Listing 2** is my attempt to write Haskell code to implement the **Specification**. I added helper functions (`getHouse`,`getRoom`,`getRooms`) and a `CONTAINER` instance for `Room` giving an overloaded `isIn` for both `House` and `Room`.I also added data types for 
  `House`, `Room`, and `Person`.

**Listing 2**

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
    data Room  = Room Int deriving (Show,Eq)
    data Rooms = Rooms  [Room]  deriving (Show,Eq)

    data House  =  House Int Rooms deriving (Show,Eq)
    data Person = Person {container :: House }  deriving (Show,Eq)

    getRooms::House->Rooms
    getRooms (House n rooms) = rooms

    getHouse::Person->House
    getHouse p = container p 


    getRoom::House->Room
    getRoom (House n (Rooms (x:xs)))  = x


    class CONTAINMENT container for where
     isIn :: for -> container -> Bool

    instance CONTAINMENT House  Person where
     isIn  person   (House n (Rooms rooms)) = (container person) ==  (House n (Rooms rooms)) ||  isIn  person  (getRooms (House n (Rooms rooms)))

    instance CONTAINMENT Rooms Person where
     isIn person (Rooms []) = False
     isIn person (Rooms (room:rooms)) = (room == getRoom(getHouse(person))) ||  isIn person (Rooms rooms)

    r1 = Room 1
    r2 = Room 2
    h1 = House 1 (Rooms [])
    h2 = House 2 (Rooms [r1])
    h3 = House 3 (Rooms [r1,r2])
    p1 = Person {container = h1}
    p2 = Person  {container = h2}
    p3 = Person  {container = h3}
    personInHoseNoRooms = isIn p1 h1
    personInHoseNoRoomsNotIn = isIn p1 h2
    personInRoomInHouse = isIn p2 h2
    personIn2ndRoomInHouse = isIn p3 h3
```

This code seems to be broadly consistent with the **Specification** . However, I see some problems:

1. If the first argument of the disjunct in `isIn` is false and the second argument is true then we have information that a person is in a room but not in the house containing the room. This appears to me to be a logical contradiction, a person is not in house A, but is in a room that is in house A. This could be a error in my understanding of the specification or my coding.
2. The word *recursive* usually is usually applied to single date type, yet above the overloaded `isIn` to apply to `House` and `Rooms`, where the `House` structure contains a list of `Rooms`.  Again this could be an error on my part.
3. As it stands there is no mention of globally unique room identifiers. It may be possible that the same room number occurs in different houses which may produce ambiguous results. I think that there is some deeper problem with the `Room-House-Person` relationships that I cannot clearly articulate.

**Questions**

1. Any coding suggestions on how I could overcome the issues mentioned above.
2. Alternatively, is it actually possible to implement the **Specification**?

Comment: Is this homework, or what's the context..? Maybe this is a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com, but hard to tell...

Comment: @mb21 Definitely not homework. I am a Phd student studying the effectiveness of Haskell as an algebraic specification language as claimed in the cited [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225122360_An_Image-Schematic_Account_of_Spatial_Categories).

Comment: well, the paper is 11 years old and recommends hugs, which AFAIK is no longer recommended... but yeah, if the question is can some kinds of rooms, houses and people be modelled in Haskell, that's something a programmer could work with ;)

Answer (score 1):

With some minimal changes, at least it compiles in GHC:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

data Room  = Room Int deriving (Show,Eq)
data Rooms = Rooms [Room] deriving (Show,Eq)

data House  =  House Int Rooms deriving (Show,Eq)
data Person = Person {container :: House }  deriving (Show,Eq)

getRooms :: House -> Rooms
getRooms (House n rooms) = rooms

getHouse :: Person -> House
getHouse p = container p 

getRoom :: House -> Room
getRoom (House n (Rooms (x:xs)))  = x

class Containment c f where
 isIn :: f -> c -> Bool

instance Containment House  Person where
 isIn person (House n (Rooms rooms)) = (container person) ==  (House n (Rooms rooms)) || isIn person (getRooms (House n (Rooms rooms)))

instance Containment Rooms Person where
 isIn person (Rooms []) = False
 isIn person (Rooms (room:rooms)) = (room == getRoom(getHouse(person))) ||  isIn person (Rooms rooms)

r1 = Room 1
r2 = Room 2
h1 = House 1 (Rooms [])
h2 = House 2 (Rooms [r1])
h3 = House 3 (Rooms [r1,r2])
p1 = Person {container = h1}
p2 = Person {container = h2}
p3 = Person {container = h3}
personInHoseNoRooms      = isIn p1 h1
personInHoseNoRoomsNotIn = isIn p1 h2
personInRoomInHouse      = isIn p2 h2
personIn2ndRoomInHouse   = isIn p3 h3
```

So regarding your question, yes it can be implemented in Haskell.

Regarding the statement:

> if the house contains her or, recursively, if the house contains a container (e.g., a room) containing her.

I agree with you that `recursively` is not the right word, it should be `transitively`.

Comment: So despite my misgivings 1) and 2), my code actually seems to satisfies the Textual Description.

Comment: @PatrickBrowne so, it _does_ answer your question then? :) I've only skimmed the paper... but personally, I'm highly skeptical of modelling general human semantics in _any_ formal language... see e.g. https://web.archive.org/web/20150626063921/http://www.betaversion.org/~stefano/linotype/news/431/

Comment: @PatrickBrowne feel free to accept the answer then, or clarify your question.

Comment: I think that your solution has the same issues 1),2), and 3) (just added) as my own attempt. I could be wrong, any clarification would be welcome.

Comment: well, about 1.) that "specification" is very ambiguous, so not sure what you want us to do here... clarify the specification? that wouldn't be a good fit for stackoverflow... I added a few sentences addressing 2.) Finally, 3.): you're free to redefine identity (i.e. `Eq`) in any way you see fit...

Comment: Yes, given the errors and ambiguity,I think the solution is about as near as possible to the specification. Thanks for your help.